Need for std::atomic when using std::mutex lock/unlock
Based on some recent comments I have seen (Minimal example of C++ concurrency bug due to one thread loading the value at thread startup & What exactly is std::atomic?) I am wondering if I am implemented multi-threading correctly in c++.
My concern is that while I am protecting the critical section of my code (correctly I think?) with mutexes it seems that if I change a variable within that section it may not be seen to be updated in other threads due to memory ordering, caching, etc.
I have tried to reduce this to a minimal code example (see below) and I would like to know if what I am doing will work as expected, or if there are additional steps I need to take to ensure that all of the threads see the same values for variables outside of the thread.  In particular I am concerned about seeing the proper value of cur_scan_line as referenced via the pointer passed as an argument to the thread, but I am open to other comments as well.
The following code is representative of my use case:
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

std::mutex row_mutex;
std::mutex image_mutex;

using Image = std::vector<int>;

int get_next_row(int thread_id, int *cur_row) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(row_mutex);

    int ret = *cur_row;

    if (ret >= 0) {
        std::cerr << "\rScanlines remaining: " << *cur_row << " (" << thread_id << ")\n"
                  << std::flush;
        *cur_row = *cur_row - 1;
    }

    return ret;
}

void worker_function(int thread_id, Image this_image, int *cur_row) {
    int row;

    while ((row = get_next_row(thread_id, cur_row)) >= 0) {
        // Real function does a lot of work here based on the value of cur_row

        image_mutex.lock();
        this_image[row] = row;
        image_mutex.unlock();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const int image_height = 100;

    Image dummy_image(image_height);

    int cur_scan_line = image_height - 1;

    int num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    num_threads = std::max(num_threads, 1);

    std::cout << "Threads to spawn: " << num_threads << "\n";

    std::vector<std::thread> worker_threads;

    for (int worker = 0; worker < num_threads; ++worker) {
        std::thread th(worker_function, worker, dummy_image, &cur_scan_line);
        worker_threads.push_back(std::move(th));
    }

    for (auto &worker : worker_threads) {
        worker.join();
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

This code was compiled with the following command and seems to run as expected, but I don't know if there are any hidden race conditions that I am not dealing with appropriately.
c++ -std=c++17 -Wall -pedantic example.cpp


Minor point: you don't need to explicitly flush std::cerr. It's unit buffered, so it always flushes its output.

@PeteBecker good point, I hadn't that out about that.

Locking a mutex serves as an acquire operation, unlocking as a release in terms of memory ordering guarantees. In short, every memory write that takes place prior to unlocking the mutex will be visible to any thread that locks the mutex later. See for example here for an explanation: https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/

you are using two unassociated mutexes.  Worker function can read from *cur_row while another thread is writing to it since image_mutex doesn't stop get_next_row from modifying *cur_row while it reads its value.

@NathanOliver That's OK in my use case, those two mutexs protect independent resources. Oh, I see what you mean.  Let me edit my code.  I think I made an error in attempting to minimize the example.  The *cur_row in the [] shouldn't be there.  In reality I'm using row to index the data structure and it's more complex than just a vector as in this example.

@Homer512 OK, so the mutex doesn't just prevent simultaneous access to the same resource it also ensure that all of the memory changes are then visible to the other threads?  If that's the case could you make your comment an answer?

Unrelated: Prefer to not lock mutexes manually. Use a lock_guard or similar that will lock and unlock the mutex automatically (locking upon creation, unlocking on destruction).

@TedLyngmo Good point.  I should replace the lock/unlock for the second critical section with a lock_guard like I did the first.

I am pretty sure you want your worker_function to accept Image by reference.

Somewhat related: your threads are racing to work on current scanline (and advance it), while it would be much more efficient to assign some consecutive scanlines to each of the threads and let them work independently in parallel. This would avoid lock contention and let them finish faster.

@KrzysiekKarbowiak This is just a toy example, the real code typically has minutes of work per scan line.  Slicing up the data by scan line seemed like the simplest approach to deal out the data to the different threads.
